# Significance of "&" in ldap query search filter

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to query LDAP/ActiveDirecory server for users and groups information. I am using search filters and I am not able to find enough documentation on this. I am interested in understanding what "&" does in the below query.

```
String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=group)(objectSid=" + sid + "))";
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search(ldapSearchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);
```

Can some one explain and point to any documents that help in understanding how to query ldap for any kind of infomraiton.

Comment: It means 'and', as stated in the LDAP Filter Syntax RFC.

Comment: give credit where credit is due. Accepting an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated by EJP in the question's comment section, the symbol simply is an 'AND' operator. All conditions must be met while evaluating any record in the recordset.

```
sampleFilter = (&condition1(condition2))
//records having both condition 1 AND condition 2 true will be returned from the directory.
```

What your searchFilter assignment statement does is that it'll do the LDAP search based on the filters provided by you. Its search filter will return all objects corresponding to group type AND whose objectsID = .

```
String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=group)(objectSid=" + sid + "))";
```

In this case, all the records which corresponding to groups in Directory, and whose sID is the one which is being passed as sID will be returned.

For your case, in simpler words, searchFilter = (group having sID: ).

The documentation section would be relevant based on the Directory Service which you're using. Please refer to the document for [Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx), if you're using Microsoft's Active Directory Services.